# How to access additional form data sent from jquery file upload in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery file upload to upload large files in chunks to server. I need to send additional data to server along with the file.

I found [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data) article that suggests adding formData as below.

```
$form = $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            maxChunkSize: 3000000,
            url: '/FileAPI/Upload',
            formData: { example: 'test' }
         });
```

How can I access the formData from HttpContext.Request in asp.net core ? Where is it available? 
Thanks for any suggestions.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Upload")]

public ActionResult Upload()
{
    var CurrentContext = HttpContext.Request;
}
```

Comment: Is the form data a model (in your models folder)? Can I suggest adding a `[FromBody] myclass formdata` as input to your `ActionResult`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How can I access the formData from HttpContext.Request in asp.net core ?**

From the article you provide , "formData object, formData: {example: 'test'} will arrive on server-side as POST parameter"

You could also try the following method to get it :

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("Upload")]
 public void Upload()
 {
        var dict = Request.Form.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString());
       //In that case, you could iterate over your dictionary or you can access values directly:
        var CurrentContext = dict["example"];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

just add it to the function signature

this should work

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Upload")]
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files, string example)
{   
   //do something with data
}
```